# Creating simple list from calendar dates Python

Tags: python, list, numpy, matrix, calendar

I have used the calendar.py module in Python:

```
for day in list(calendar.monthcalendar(2017,calmonth)):
    print(day)
```

to create a matrix for a month as:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
[16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22]
[23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29]
[30, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

I want to transform this into a simple list like:

```
(1,2,3,4....31)
```

This would mean getting rid of the zeroes and transforming the matrix into a list.

I have tried first turning it into an array with numpy:

```
for day in list(calendar.monthcalendar(2017,calmonth)):
    print(day)
    dayarray = np.squeeze(np.asarray(day))
    print(dayarray)
```

But no other numpy formulas for getting rid of zeroes or transforming into a list seem to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to use `monthcalendar`, there are `calendar.py` functions much better suited for your needs:

```
_, ndays = calendar.monthrange(2017, 12)
l = list(range(1, ndays+1))
print(l)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can extract it with two for loops:

```
my_matrix = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
           [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8],
           [9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15],
           [16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22],
           [23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29],
           [30, 31, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

my_list = []
for array in my_matrix:
    for i in array:
        if i>0:
            my_list.append(i)

print(my_list)
```